# Заморозка движения во время прыжка UE4

Tags: unreal-engine-4, blueprint

Во время прыжка не могу двигаться, персонаж просто застывает в направлении куда я шёл раньше
Отключение или включение Override не помогает

[image: Весь мувимент:]